# Python only using first letter in string when searching keys in a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

Python beginner here. I am having a problem when attempting to search for a string within a dictionary.

The program I am writing is using xlrd to match data from a excel spreadsheet (S2name) with a dictionary key, to then return the value assigned to the key. This is for the purpose of matching quality control tests with chemical data.

The dictionary is much like this:

---

```
dQC = {'4266152-001': 'METHOD_BLANK',
 '4266152-002': 'LCS',
 '4266152-004': 'LAB_DUPLICATE',
```

etc..

---

My code is working, except for the fact that the search function is returning the wrong result from the dictionary.

I have isolated the problem to the v variable in the following:

---

```
S2name = (sheet2.cell_value(row_index, 0))

for key, value in dQC.items(): 
    def search(dic, lookup):   
        for v in key:  
            print("This should be the key in dQC, not the number %s" % v)
            if v in lookup:    
                return v   # I would obviously return value here, but it returns the wrong one.
            else:
                return False

QCtype = (search(dQC, S2name))

print(QCtype)
```

Result:

```
This should be the key in dQC, not the number 4
4
```

---

For some reason, v is searching for only the first digit in the string (ie: 4) and not the whole string (ie: 4266152-001), so when I call the value using QCtype, it returns the wrong one. I would like v to use the first 10 characters when iterating the search, not he first.

Note, in the script, I am returning v just to check it. I would otherwise be returning value.

EDIT:

Perhaps it is clearer if I link to the thread that I used some of the code from.

I was under the assumption that this would search for the entire word in the dictionary key, not for the individual letters in key, which makes sense to me now.

[How to search if dictionary value contains certain string with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340922/how-to-search-if-dictionary-value-contains-certain-string-with-python)

Comment: Why are you iterating over the key at all?  The key is just one string; just use it directly.

Comment: Why are you defining the search function inside the for loop?

Comment: in you code v is a character in the string key. `search` function returns that character when `lookup` has the character also. it does not return the wrong one.

Answer (score 4):

You're defining many functions named `search`, each obliterating the other, and at the end only calling the last one you happened to have defined.  It's unusual to use the `def` statement in a loop, and surely wrong to use `def` but not call/use that function within each leg of the loop.

Moreover, `for v in key:`, where `key` is a string, assigns to `v`, in succession, each of the **characters** in `key`.

It's hard to fathom exactly what you think you're doing, but I imagine you'd want to define `search` just once and then maybe **call** it in a loop.  Perhaps something like:

```
def search(dic, lookup, valur):   
    return lookup.get(key, value)

for key, value in dQC.items():
    QCtype = search(dQC, S2name)
    print(QCtype)
```

...?