# Python searching for dict values in list: TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, key-value

I'm referring to the following code provided by Klaus Byskov Pedersen ([How to search if dictionary value contains certain string with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340922/how-to-search-if-dictionary-value-contains-certain-string-with-python)).

**Goal:** I want to substitute "Mary" with a list that consists out of 150+ strings. However, When I try to provide a list instead of a "Mary" into the search function I receive this error:
`TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not list`

**Ask:** I tried to wrap searchFor in the if statement in [], but received the same error. What am I doing wrong? Ideally, I want the search function to tell me what values in myList are also in myDict.

Code provided below:

```
myDict = {'age': ['12'], 'address': ['34 Main Street, 212 First Avenue'],
      'firstName': ['Alan', 'Mary-Ann'], 'lastName': ['Stone', 'Lee']}

def search(values, searchFor):
    for k in values:
        for v in values[k]:
            if searchFor in v:
                return k
    return None

#Checking if string 'Mary' exists in dictionary value
print search(myDict, 'Mary') #prints firstName
```

Answer (score 0):

If your using python3 use print(search(myDict, 'Mary')), other than that it works! can you be more specific what is your problem

Comment: I want to replace "Mary" with a list containing 150+ strings. Ideally I want to have the function tell me what values in my list are also in mydict.

Answer (score 0):

If you need your `function` to search multiple items contained in a `list` then include the last print statement in a for like this,

```
l1=['Mary','Main','Lee']
for i in l1:
    print(search(myDict, i))
```

code:

```
myDict = {'age': ['12'], 'address': ['34 Main Street, 212 First Avenue'],
      'firstName': ['Alan', 'Mary-Ann'], 'lastName': ['Stone', 'Lee']}

def search(values, searchFor):
    for k in values:
        for v in values[k]:
            if searchFor in v:
                return k
    return None

l1=['Mary','Main','Lee']
for i in l1:
    print(search(myDict, i))
```

output:

```
firstName
address
lastName
```

Let me know if I understood it correctly.

Comment: Thank you for helping out! What I need is the dict value being returned, not the dict key. I want to be able to see if the values in the list are present in the dict and if so what is the dict value. Hope this makes sense and can be done?